# How do you make volume keys and mute key work in Xmonad

Tags: audio, xmonad

I am new to Xmonad (just installed it yesterday), and since I have never used haskell before, I found configuration a little bit confusing for me. I got somewhat made xmobar and trayer work, but I have no idea how might I make multimedia keys to adjust volume. Can anyone help with that?

Additional question: How do you manage your volume in xmonad. Do you use tray icon, or other things like that?

Here is my xmonad configuration:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import System.IO

main = xmonad =<< statusBar myBar myPP toggleStrutKey myConfig

-- Command to launch the bar
myBar = "xmobar"

-- Custom PP, it determines what is written to the bar
myPP = xmobarPP { ppCurrent = xmobarColor "#429942" "" . wrap "<" ">" }

-- Key bindings to toggle the gap for the bar
toggleStrutKey XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask} = (modMask, xK_b)

myConfig = defaultConfig {
    manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig,
    layoutHook = avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig,
    modMask = mod4Mask -- Rebind Mod to windows key
    } `additionalKeys`
    [ ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_z), spawn "xscreensaver-command -lock")
    ]
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use 'xev' and tap the multimedia keys to discover their names. One might be 'XF86XK_AudioMute'. Then look at the contents of '/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h' and look for the name. On my system, 'XF86XK_AudioMute' is '0x1008FF12'.

Drop that where you would put a key in your config file. It might look like this:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import System.IO
```

-CUT-

```
 } `additionalKeys`
    [ ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_z), spawn "xscreensaver-command -lock"),
      ((0                     , 0x1008FF11), spawn "amixer -q sset Master 2%-"),
      ((0                     , 0x1008FF13), spawn "amixer -q sset Master 2%+"),
      ((0                     , 0x1008FF12), spawn "amixer set Master toggle")
    ]
```

'amixer' will set your volume. The '0' replacing mod4Mask allows you to tap the multimedia key without holding your mod key.

Comment: When I use *xev* and press volume keys on my HP laptop I get no keycodes, but *showkey* command show them as keycode 114 and keycode 115. How do I need to change this XMonad config file to work with my keys?

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.04 this worked copy/paste without looking up the keys symbols.

Comment: If the mute above cannot unmute, try `amixer -D pulse set Master toggle` instead.

Comment: Mute key problem: When I start `xev` and press mute key, there's nothing to find in the terminal. (Other keys are fine.) I looked up from `/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h`, I found this: `#define XF86XK_AudioMute 0x1008FF12   /* Mute sound from the system */` Do you know what's the problem with my mute key? Thank you.

Comment: Another `Mute` key problem: I can't find the name for Mute either. (I use ThinkPad.)

Answer (score 19):

See this [Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.9/docs/Graphics-X11-ExtraTypes-XF86.html) for keys you want and add to your config file:

```
import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86
myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
[ ...
, ((0, xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume   ), spawn "amixer set Master 2-")
, ((0, xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume   ), spawn "amixer set Master 2+")
, ((0, xF86XK_AudioMute          ), spawn "amixer set Master toggle")
...]
```

Comment: I get an error with this config:
"xmonad.hs:29:1: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
Please check the file for errors."

That line is where "[ ..." begins ...

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: To use Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86 is the better solution for readability.

Comment: @valentt The line with the dots is just an example. It should look like that, so instead of the three dots you have your first key defined: `[ ((modMask,               xK_e     ), spawn "dmenu_run")`

Answer (score 10):

If you're using pulseaudio, `pactl` also should work.

```
, ((0 , xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume 0 +1.5%")
, ((0 , xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume 0 -- -1.5%")
, ((0 , xF86XK_AudioMute), spawn "pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle")
]
```

`0` is sink id. `pactl list short sinks` will show sink list.

```
pactl stat|grep 'Default Sink' | cut -f2 -d':'
```

will show current default sink. You can use sink name instead numeric id.

Doulble dash `--` tells 'this is not option(like -h), just value' to `pactl`.

Comment: Nice! However, the `--` didn't work for me on 15.10, just removing it did the trick. Also, there is a special name `@DEFAULT_SINK@`, so you don't need to fiddle around with device specific numbers/names.

Comment: This is perfect, replacing `0` with `@DEFAULT_SINK@` in the above commands! At least for those switching from other DEs -- thanks a lot to you!

Comment: This answer has the benefit of going over 100% instead of capping (like amixer caps). The bad thing is that it stops working when you play the music from different sink.

Answer (score 4):

If `amixer set Master 2-` does not work. Try `amixer -D pulse set Master 2-` instead. Also `2%-` and `2%+` will change the volume by 2 percent, which may be easier to use. You can test these commands in the terminal to adjust them to your liking before you put them in you xmonad config file.

Comment: `... -D pulse ...` worked for me! also, a `-q` flag quiets the output